# If statement to move past [ ] in a https get response

Tags: javascript, get

I am trying to write a trading algo and I am moving through tickers for quote. When I come to a certain tickers that responds with []. My list stops iterating. I have tried several different if statements to move past any ticker that returns  [] but it is still stopping on these tickers, any ideas?

```
if(msg == undefined || msg == []){
         count++
         nextTicker()
         getVolume()
        // console.log("Next Ticker: ", nextTicker1, "Next Quote: ", nextQuote1)
        // console.log(msg)
       }else if(msg.price == null || msg.price == undefined){
         count++
         nextTicker()
         getVolume()
       }else if(msg.price != null){
         count++
         nextTicker()
         getVolume()
         console.log("Next Ticker: ", nextTicker1, "Next Quote: ", nextQuote1)
         console.log(msg)
       }
```

[example of ticker response via a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1TAY.png)

[example of a good ticker response via algo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqSVH.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can't compres two arrays, since JS objects are stored in memory as reference, this comparisson returns always false:

```js
let arr1 = [];
let arr2 = [];

console.log(arr1 == arr2);  // Always false in JS
```

To check an empty array you can get his length, try this:

```js
let arr = [];
console.log(arr.length == 0)
```

In your code you have to do this:

```js
if(msg.length == 0){
  // your code
}
```

Comment: This is wrong: msg == undefined, replace it with msg.length == 0

Comment: i currently have it as this      if(msg == undefined || msg.length == 0){
         count++
         nextTicker()
         getVolume()
        // console.log("Next Ticker: ", nextTicker1, "Next Quote: ", nextQuote1)
        // console.log(msg)
       }

And it is still stuck.

Comment: remove this: " msg == undefined || " , leave only: " msg.length == 0 "

Comment: if either threshold is met it should work regardless but needless ot say i also tried that as well.

Comment: issue was the api was hitting its limits

Comment: Works now? Anyway remember you cant compares two objects in JS.

Comment: Yes. Issue was i was iterating through 10,000 tickers and the api said I had unlimited request but it didnt specify how many request per second. So I was essential over running the server with requests. So I guess I need to send a block of tickers then sew the responses back into one large array. This should be interesting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The response is not `[]`, it's `[ ]` in this link:

[example of ticker response via a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1TAY.png)